# How can I make visible an invisible control with jquery? (hide and show not work)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, controls, visibility, visual-studio-2008-sp1

How can I change the visibility of a control with jQuery? I have a control that its visible property to false (not css).

When I used `show()` function for it nothing happened, it seems that `hide()` and `show()` methods are for css set of a control, not visible property.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can't do this with jQuery, `visible="false"` in asp.net means the control *isn't rendered into the page*.  If you want the control to go to the client, you need to do `style="display: none;"` so it's actually in the HTML, otherwise there's literally nothing for the client to show, since the element wasn't in the HTML your server sent.

If you remove the `visible` attribute and add the `style` attribute you can then use jQuery to show it, like this:

```
$("#elementID").show();
```

---

### Old Answer (before [patrick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick) catch)

To change `visibility`, you need to use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), like this:

```
$("#elem").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Unless you need to have the element occupy page space though, use `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;` in your CSS, then just do:

```
$("#elem").show();
```

The [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) functions deal with `display` instead of `visibility`, like most of the jQuery functions :)

Comment: The OP stated "(not css)". I can't imagine what that means, though.

Comment: @patrick - Ohhhhh, that's an ASP.Net thing, totally different answer, I'll update.

Comment: that is very very bad for me .....

imagine that i have two buttons next together and when one of them is invisible (from codebehind)so the other one can fill it's space and this is exactly what i want....
i forced to invisible that button for some conditions and also forced to visible it with jquery and invisible the other one with jquery....

so with css -> hidden control i have white space ... how can i fill it by visible button???


however really really thanks for your attention and your answer//
best regards/....

Comment: @LostLord - That's the part of the answer covering `display`, if you use `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;`, then it won't occupy any space in the page while hidden.

Answer (score 7):

.show() and .hide() modify the css display rule. I think you want:

```
$(selector).css('visibility', 'hidden'); // Hide element
$(selector).css('visibility', 'visible'); // Show element
```

Comment: that is very very bad for me ..... imagine that i have two buttons next together and when one of them is invisible (from codebehind)so the other one can fill it's space and this is exactly what i want.... i forced to invisible that button for some conditions and also forced to visible it with jquery and invisible the other one with jquery.... so with css -> hidden control i have white space ... how can i fill it by visible button??? however really really thanks for your attention and your answer// best regards/....

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I use to deal with this.

First we show the element, which will typically set the display type to "block" via .show() function, and then set the CSS rule to "visible":

```
jQuery( '.element' ).show().css( 'visibility', 'visible' );
```

Or, assuming that the class that is hiding the element is called hidden, such as in Twitter Bootstrap, toggleClass() can be useful:

```
jQuery( '.element' ).toggleClass( 'hidden' );
```

Lastly, if you want to chain functions, perhaps with fancy with a fading effect, you can do it like so:

```
jQuery( '.element' ).css( 'visibility', 'visible' ).fadeIn( 5000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been more than 10 years and not sure if anyone still finding this question or answer relevant.

But a quick workaround is just to wrap the `asp control` within a `html container`

```
<div id="myElement" style="display: inline-block">
   <asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Whenever the `Javascript Event` is triggered, if it needs to be an event by the `asp control`, just wrap the `asp control` around the `div` container.

```
<div id="testG">  
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Activate" />
</div>
```

The jQuery Code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testG").click(function () {
                $("#myElement").css("display", "none");
     });
});
```